# Multiple occurances of same signal at signal handler

Tags: linux, kernel, signals, handler, interprocess

I have 3  non-related processes running simultaneously (**2 daemon processes running in background** and **1 main process running in foreground**).

I have created signal handler for SIGUSR1 in one of the daemon process and other processes are trying to send a signal using kill(pid, SIGUSR1).

When I am sending just one signal, it works fine. When I send it in this way, it works fine too :

kill(pid, SIGUSR1);

sleep(5);

kill(pid, SIGUSR1);

sleep(5);

kill(pid, SIGUSR1);

sleep(5);

This works fine, the signal handler is executed thrice which I am monitoring on syslog.

**But when I remove the sleep and send them directly one after another, signal handler should be executed thrice (ideally), but instead it just executes once or twice.**. It is not able to execute the signal handler if I send the same signal back to back multiple times.

Ideally it should go in the pending signals and be executed once the current handler execution is finished. I had also read that if the same signal is sent multiple times then it ignores the multiple instances, so is there a way where all the instances be executed one after another rather than ignoring them.

is there anything I am missing or going wrong ?

I need this kind of execution to work because there would be multiple processes which would send SIGUSR1 signal to one particular daemon processes so I am trying to run without any sleep.

Thanks for the help

Comment: "it does not work" Can you be more precise: the signal handler is called once? the deamon crash?...

Comment: A [MCVE] could be usefull here, what's inside the signal handler?

Comment: @purplepsycho The daemon is not crashing. Inside signal handler, I am just writing to syslog saying that particular signal has arrived. When I send kill(pid, SIGUSR1) back to back 4 times(without any delay), the signal handler only executes twice (instead signal handler should be executed 4 times as the signal was sent 4 times ), so it would be great if you could suggest something. I also read about setprocmask to block the interrupt signals, but it does not seem to help here as signal handler is only executed twice. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: There is no signal queue. There is a binary flag. A signal is either pending or not. If a signal is pending, for example because the same signal is currently being handled, you can send the same signal multiple times and the situation won't change, it will remain pending.

Comment: Exactly, if a signal is currently handled, and lets say some other processes send the same signal multiple times, then I want them to execute too. Right now, they are ignored. Is there a way out to still execute the handler for same signal when the handler is finished processing the current signal handle ?  Thanks for the help

Comment: I think that `syslog` takes too much time to be used in a signal handler. You could just have a counter in the signal handler and a companion thread that will decrease the counter and call `syslog`

Comment: You might try [sigqueue](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html)